# Extra routes being created when assigning virtual network interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, route

I'm running a Ubuntu VPS that I'm using as a squid proxy server. From my provider I've got a load of IP addresses which I'm assigning as virtual interfaces within `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg` like the following:

```
#Endpoint_48
auto eth0:48
iface eth0:48 inet static
address 91.xxx.xxx.xx
Netmask 255.255.255.255
Broadcast 91.xxx.xxx.xx
```

The issue I'm having is that upon boot, Ubuntu seems to be creating loads of extra routes, some of which will have such large subnets that I'm unable to reach any website on those subnets. E.g. This created route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
91.0.0.0        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
```

... will prevent me from reaching `http://ubuntu.com` which at present is on `91.189.94.40`

Removing these routes with `route del` solves the issue, but they appear again on reboot. Any thoughts on how to prevent them from appearing entirely?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really have capital `N` and capital `B` in the configuration file? if so, that is most likely the reason for the issue you are facing, since those are not recognized options in network configuration files.

The correct directives are `netmask` and `broadcast`.

Comment: That was totally it, thanks! Please send over your bitcoin address and I'll send you beer money!